# Django Microservices Admin Authentication

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am building an application using Django Web Framework and Django Rest Framework (Microservices architecture). It has 3 services:

1. Authentication
2. Sa
3. Sb

The Authentication service needs django inbuilt authentication Middleware. But those are not required in Sa and Sb.

How can i get rid of those in other services ?
and also How will the admin view of other services will work ?, I meant the Login for viewing the default admin site in django.

Currently the expected flow is

If any request comes to Sa then first a call will be made to Authentication service to verify the jwt token and then it will be processed.